# how to update a document without overwriting the existing one?

Tags: mongodb

I'm studying how to use mongoDB.

I want to update a certain field of a document but it overwrites the whole document. How can I update only the field in a document I want to modify?

```
db.products.find({_id: 1})

{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "name" : "aaa",
    "category" : "toy",
    "price" : 100.0
}
```

For example, I have a document like this.

```
db.products.update({_id: 1}, {price:999})

db.products.find({_id: 1})

{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "price" : 999.0
}
```

When I update like this, I get this result. I lost name field and category field after executing update command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the operator [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

```
$ db.products.update({_id: 1}, {$set: {price:999}})
```

This operator allows you update the specified field(s).

Comment: If you $set  a sub document , eg `{ foo: { bar: 1 , baz: true}}`and do a `{$set: { foo: {bar: "aah"}}` then foo is `{bar: "aah"}`and `baz` is gone...

Answer (score 2):

Using the `$set` operator, you should be able to update only the column that you want to modify or else it will overwrite the whole document.

You can follow more about the usage of `$set` operator [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set)

Finally your update query should be something as like this:

```
db.products.update({_id: 1}, {$set: {price:999}})
```